# scss compile error no mixin named transalate property

Tags: html, css, scss-mixins

no mixin named transition
after compiling i am getting this error here its code

this error code

> {
>     "status": 1,
>     "file": "/Users/chetandhargalkar/Documents/medino/assets/sass/layout/_header.scss",
>     "line": 36,
>     "column": 30,
>     "message": "no mixin named transition",
>     "formatted": "Error: no mixin named transition\n        on line 36 of assets/sass/layout/_header.scss\n        from line 11 of assets/sass/main.scss\n>>                     @include transition(all .3s ease-in-out)\r\n   -----------------------------^\n"
>   }

here its my code

```
.social-links {
  ul {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    li {
      display: inline;
      margin-left: 15px;
      a {
        color: $body-text;
        @include transition(all .3s ease-in-out);
        &:hover {
          color: $primary-color;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transition is not a mixin, it is a standard CSS property. Replace this:

```
@include transition(all .3s ease-in-out);
```

with this:

```
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a mixin you can create one which you can you everywhere in your theme.

```
@mixin transition($val, $timer, $ease) {
    transition: $val $timer $ease;
}
```

use like:

```
a {
  @include transition(all, .3s, ease-in-out);
}
```

or just use regular css:

```
a {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```